# Plotly to word, problems with kaleido

Tags: python, plotly, docx, kaleido

The code below works just fine on most laptops. But in certain apps it just doesn't get to work well. Also it didn't work on a laptop of a colleague of mine.
Any idea what could cause the problem?

```
from io import BytesIO
from pathlib import Path

from docx import Document
from docx.document import _Body
from docx.text.paragraph import Paragraph
from plotly import graph_objs as go

path_template = Path(__file__).parent / "template.docx"
doc = Document(docx=str(path_template))
body: _Body = doc._body  # pylint: disable=protected-access
cur_par: Paragraph = body.paragraphs[-1]

_fig = go.Figure(data=
go.Contour(
    z=[[10, 10.625, 12.5, 15.625, 20],
       [5.625, 6.25, 8.125, 11.25, 15.625],
       [2.5, 3.125, 5., 8.125, 12.5],
       [0.625, 1.25, 3.125, 6.25, 10.625],
       [0, 0.625, 2.5, 5.625, 10]]
))

cur_par.add_run().add_picture(image_path_or_stream=BytesIO(_fig.to_image(format="png")))
doc.save("New file.docx")
```

Error message in production and on a laptop of a colleague of mine:
[image]

Comment: Did you check the versions of plotly and kaleido on these laptops ?